# Installing a group of files with puppet and hiera

Tags: puppet, hiera

I have a puppet config that correctly installs a file.  I want it to install several files.  The config looks roughly like this (in the part that is relevant here):

```
$stuff = hiera('stuff')
$site_filename = $stuff['site_file']

file { "/path/to/my/file/called/$site_filename":
  ensure  => present,
  owner   => 'the-owner',
  group   => 'the-group',
  mode    => 644,
  source  => "puppet:///modules/this-module/$site_filename",
  require => [Package['something'],
      User['someone']]
}
file { "/path/to/my/symlink/called/$site_filename":
  ensure  => 'link',
  target  => "/path/to/my/file/called/$site_filename",
  require => Package['something'],
}
```

Works great, the right file is installed on the right host.  But I'd now like to install a variable number of (very similar) files, the number being different on each host.

My hiera files currently look like this:

```
stuff:
  site_file: "hey-i-am-the-site-file-on-host-awesomeness"
```

In principle, I want to say something like this:

```
stuff:
  site_file: ["hey-i-am-the-site-file-on-host-awesomeness",
              "i-am-also-a-site-file-for-awesomeness",
              "do-not-forget-me-too",
              "someday-you-will-want-me-as-well"]
```

And here I am hitting the limits of my puppet and hiera knowledge.  I understand that when I think I should iterate in puppet, I'm probably wrong, but I'm a bit confused how to do this.

Any pointers on how to do it or what to read about to learn?

Comment: It's hard to believe that what you present "Works great" when it is syntactically incorrect and presents duplicate resources.  Let's start with something that actually could work, shall we?

Comment: Additionally, which version of Puppet is this for?  An answer for Puppet 3 (with future parser disabled) could be substantially different from one for Puppet 4.

Comment: This is puppet 3.7.2.  Given that I've said this is a snippet of a manifest, what is syntactically incorrect?  (Ah, in simplifying, I did duplicate the filename, fixed.)

Comment: You didn't mention whether you are using the future parser or not though.

Comment: Ah, sorry.  I am not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puppet 4 and has some iteration functions that would be applicable here, and these are available also in recent Puppet 3 with the future parser enabled.  They are not available in Puppet 3 without the future parser, however, so you need a different solution.

The classic way to approach problems such as this is to rely on the fact that a resource declaration in which the title is an array (literal or array-valued variable) declares a separate resource for each element of the array.  This is often combined with a defined type as the resource to directly declare.  This combination is roughly equivalent to a foreach loop over the array elements, with the defined-type body as its body.  Example:

```
define mymodule::sitefile() {
    file { "/path/to/my/file/called/$title":
      ensure  => present,
      owner   => 'the-owner',
      group   => 'the-group',
      mode    => 644,
      source  => "puppet:///modules/mymodule/$title",
      require => [Package['something'], User['someone']]
    }

    file { "/path/to/my/symlink/called/$title":
      ensure  => 'link',
      target  => "/path/to/my/file/called/$title",
      require => Package['something']
    }
}

# ...

$stuff = hiera('stuff')
mymodule::sitefile { $stuff['site_file']: }
```

Comment: This is definitely the prevalent template for pre-lambda iteration in Puppet (define with hash passed in). This answer will be helpful to potentially point others toward in the future.

Comment: Thanks, that does precisely what I want and also demystifies an element of puppet that clearly will help in the future.